# import com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile is not working

Tags: android

I ported my eclipse project to android studio project. This particular import has problem! Not sure how to resolve. Please help?

Comment: and what problems do you have exactly?

Comment: Error:(7, 45) error: package com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile does not exist

Comment: Error:(72, 139) error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 as well

Comment: have you checked if the required dependencies are in the classpath?

Comment: In android studio  ??

Comment: just googling "android studio migration from eclipse" gave me this result http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/migrate.html you should try to research a bit more before asking for help

Comment: Thanks for it. I tried all the steps. I have issues only with this import statement

Comment: then you should edit your question, including everything you tried, and copy the code of your build file, so we can try to detect the issue